# How to reinitialize plugin when element is display none

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem and can't get out of it. I am using different jquery plugins such as : nanoScroller, iDangerous swiper, etc.

My problem is when an element is set to display none the plug-in wont work until I resize my screen or if I press f12 the plugin-in works.

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Trigger window resize, or initialize element when you show that item

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I tried reinitialize the plugin but it wont work either.

Comment: Im also using bootstrap. By default bootstrap modal is in display none and it become display block when you toggle it. Im using nanoScroller on my modal and the scrollbar wont appear but when I resize the screen it works

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering window resize event:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

---

If you wish to initialize some elements after bs modal has been show, use [it's events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events):

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {alert('before modal show')});
```

Comment: because display none have no width and height so the nanoScroller dont initialize because it needs width and height to work.

Comment: nanoScroller is not the only one. Im using also swiper.js in bootstrap nav-tabs and also the problem because by default inactive tabs are hidden.

Comment: @RafaelTopasi Have you tried `shown.bs.modal` event?